# Error loading operating system

Tags: windows-8.1, usb, operating-systems, bootable-media

I am having a problem installing windows 8.1 on Hp elitebook from Bootable USB.. It says:
"Error Loading Operating System", it does not give any other error code/number. 
While I used this same Usb to install the windows on my other laptop and it is working fine there.Only difference between the two machines is one is hp elitebook and other is hp probook.

Can anyone know what is the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: Welcome to superuser, does it give any other information, an error number etc, was your other install on the same type of computer, are you loading from a usb, cd, dvd, restore partition, etc any info helps

Comment: Run the hard drive diagnostics from the bios and post back any error messages. http://h20565.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c01443317

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a problem with hard disk, I reformatted everything on it and then used the bootable usb and it worked. Thanks to all for helping..